# Injected Service needs to be public if I intend to use it in .HTML file of the component?

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection

For example I inject my dependency:

```
constructor(public authService: AuthService) { }
```

Then I implement it in the .html of my component I injected into:

```
<li class="nav-item" *ngIf = "!authService.isLoggedIn">
    <a href="/admin/login" class="nav-link">Login</a>
</li>
```

If the property is private or protected I get the following error: "
*Property 'authService' is protected and only accessible within class 'HeaderComponent' and its subclasses.* "

I'm inexperienced but I have a feeling that having the property as public is unacceptable and should be either private or protected. I've been fiddling about trying to solve this issue for quite a while now and I need to know what's up.

Comment: From a technical perspective, everything retrieved from the component should be public (either explicitly, or implicitly). This is just a typescript design-time requirement, although you may not be able to compile. Whether is is correct to expose your services is a matter of opinion. I would say you should only expose the bare minimum that the HTML needs. But that's just an opinion.

Comment: In addition to what @Kurt Hamilton said, the `private`/`protected` should be used only for encapsulation, not security.

Comment: Changing it to
```
public isLoggedIn = null;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    this.isLoggedIn = authService.isLoggedIn;
   }
```
Did solve my problem, thanks for the tip! Can you apply the same method for functions and not just properties?

Comment: @AdamoModelo I would generally try to avoid calling functions from your HTML (other than event handlers) where possible. I would definitely avoid calling your service directly. One principle of layered design is that each layer only communicates with the adjacent layer. Having your HTML communicate directly with your service bypasses the component and violates this principle. It's not necessarily a strict rule, but does encourage best practice.